# Issue with Regex for Canadian postal code

Tags: regex

I am using this regex but I am having an issue in Asp validation can someone help?

```
^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][ -]?\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$/i
```

Trying to match,
X#X #X#,
X#X-#X#,
X#X#X#

```
    <Label For="PostalCode" Text="*Postal Code:" /><br>
          <TextBox ID="PostalCode" class="txt postal postalError" DataField="PostalCode" Placeholder="A1A 1A1" DataType="String" /> <br/>       
          <Validate Target="PostalCode" CssClass="NormalRed xmp-validation clearfix" Type="required" text="* Postal Code is required." Message=""></Validate>
          <Validate Target="PostalCode" CssClass="NormalRed xmp-validation clearfix" Type="regex" Text="* Postal Code must be formatted as follows: A1A 1A1" Message="" ValidationExpression="^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][ -]?\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$/i"></Validate>
```

Comment: What is it you are actually using, this looks like it might be ASP.Net not Classic ASP *(which is what you have tagged the question as)*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution as the solution above doesn't factor in you can't contain the letters D, F, I, O, Q, or U, and cannot start with W or Z. I also removed the /i at the end. I also allow for lower case letters.

```
[abceghjklmnprstvxyABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[abceghjklmnprstvxyABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][ -]?\d[abceghjklmnprstvxyABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$
```

Comment: put both lower and uppercase in same character class: `[abceghjklmnprstvxyABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]` or use case insensitive flag: `^(?i)[abc...]...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\d[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z][ -]?\d[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\d$
```

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV1vL8/2)

Comment: Doesn't factor in you can't contain the letters D, F, I, O, Q, or U, and cannot start with W or Z.

Answer (score 0):

In your expression `^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][ -]?\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$/i` you have a `$/i` at the end.

The `$` means to match the end of the string, but with `/i` it looks like you're attempting to capture additional characters. This presents an impossible case. You can't have more characters after the end of the string.